# How can I debut a templatesyntax error while setting up satchmo?

Tags: django, satchmo

I am trying to install satchmo using the instructions given in the site. Everything works fine except the admin part. The moment I hit `http://<SERVER_NAME>/admin`, I get the following error:

> 'admin_static' is not a valid tag library: Template library
>   admin_static not found, tried
>   django.templatetags.admin_static,satchmo_store.shop.templatetags.admin_static,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static,django.contrib.comments.templatetags.admin_static,sorl.thumbnail.templatetags.admin_static,livesettings.templatetags.admin_static,satchmo_utils.thumbnail.templatetags.admin_static,satchmo_store.contact.templatetags.admin_static,tax.templatetags.admin_static,product.templatetags.admin_static,payment.templatetags.admin_static,satchmo_utils.templatetags.admin_static,app_plugins.templatetags.admin_static

I have no clue why is it saying that as it should be present by default.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `Django 1.5` which has dropped support for the `admin_static` tag  that satchmo tries to find. Downgrade to `1.4.5.` and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Satchmo currently requires Django 1.4+, since July 2012, according the source documentation. (Fixed outdated requirements on the home page now.)